# jQuery: remove not selected choices before appending new via AJAX for Chosen JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have my ChosenJS multiselect input, where I get options dynamically via AJAX:

```
  $("#offer_tags").chosen({
    max_selected_options: 30,
    max_shown_results: 30,
  });

  $("#offer_tags_chosen input").autocomplete({
      minLength: 3,
      source: function( request, response ) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "/common/offer_tags?search="+request.term,
              dataType: "json",
              beforeSend: function(){}
          }).done(function( data ) {
                  response(
                    $('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results').each(function () {
                      console.log(this);
                    }),
                    $('#offer_tags').append('<option>' + request.term + '</option>'),

                    $.map( data, function( item ) {
                      $('#offer_tags').append('<option value='+ item.id +'>' + item.name + '</option>');
                    })
                  );
                  $("#offer_tags").trigger("chosen:updated");
          });

      }
  });
```

At the moment it looks like everything works fine, however I'd like to remove not selected choices before new options are appended.

So far my idea has been to access `ul.chosen-results` and then remove all `li.active-results`

With this piece of code

```
$('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results').each(function () {
  console.log(this);
})
```

I can get `ul.chosen-results` in my console:

```
<ul class="chosen-results">
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0" style="">myvalue</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">othervalue</li>
  <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">thirdvalue</li>
</ul>
```

however when I try to access `children` with something like this:

```
$('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).children());
})
```

it gives me this:

```
w.fn.init [li.no-results, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
0: li.no-results
length: 1
prevObject: w.fn.init [ul.chosen-results]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Whan am I doing wrong, please? How can I remove options which are not selected before appending new options? I need to keep selected choices in place - no remove.

**Update**

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 936px;"
      title="" id="offer_tags_chosen">
  <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-field">
      <input type="text" value="Please, select (multiple allowed)"
             class="default ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off"
             style="width: 215.387px;">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0" style="">myvalue</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">othervalue</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">thirdvalue</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

`console.log($(this).children().get());` gives me:

```
[li.no-results]
0: li.no-results
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Please update your code with relevant html (you only provided the `ul` html, it's not enough, where is `#offer_tags_chosen` div?), would be good if you could do a snippet so one can help you easier.

Comment: @tcj Please, see my update above. I'll check if I can add some snippet as well.

Comment: You try to remove all li which have 'active-result' class ?

Comment: @Shree Yes, I want to remove `li.active-result`, but keep options which are selected - has class `result-selected`. With each AJAX request I can get new list of options and always keep selected, but remove those which are not selected.

Comment: Can you try with  console.log($(this).children().get());

Comment: @Shree Gives me `[li.no-results]` - see in update above. As I understand "No results" is Chosen message is no results. My AJAX can return no results and in that case I should be able to add my typed value as option - `$('#offer_tags').append('<option>' + request.term + '</option>')`

Answer (score 0):

Not from `ul` loop start from `li`.

`$('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results li'`.

Try `get()` with `not` selector like below. I add class `result-selected` on 4th `li` value which is not appear on console.

```js
$('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results li').not('.result-selected').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).get());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 936px;" title="" id="offer_tags_chosen">
  <ul class="chosen-choices">
    <li class="search-field">
      <input type="text" value="Please, select (multiple allowed)" class="default ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" style="width: 215.387px;">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="chosen-drop">
    <ul class="chosen-results">

      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0" style="">Select</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">othervalue</li>
      <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">thirdvalue</li>
      <li class="active-result result-selected" data-option-array-index="4" style="">4thvalue</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however when I implement this within my AJAX response, I get `[li.no-results]` For some reason I cannot access `$('#offer_tags_chosen ul.chosen-results li'` - it gives my just that first Chosen JS default "no results" `li`. I see my options in `chosen-results`, but can't access them. I don't know, maybe that's some Chosen JS specific thing...